# HTML/CSS/Javascript: How do I make it so .col-sm can replace @media query

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code here so that it displays each image side by side (left to right), but I want to make it so that when it is in mobile version (max-width: 480px) that it displays the pictures in 2-columns (so 2 rows). Instead of using @media query, I was wondering how can I do it via .col-sm? 
I have **PICTURE PICTURE PICTURE** and I want to change the format to when it is in mobile display to:

**PICTURE PICTURE**

**PICTURE**

```
<div class="col-9">
                <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="carrots.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="beets.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="asparagus.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I apologize if the question is very vague. I'm still new and learning about bootstrap

Comment: The html you have with the CSS you have together determine how something is displaying. There are a great deal of ways to get something to wrap as the screen becomes too small, and there are many parameters you might want to consider (centering, vertical spacing, ... ) long before you start to code. So I'd first of mall make a minimal thing add get the html and css in there, and then very detailed describe wht you need to happen as the width shrinks.

Comment: I want to go from what I have right now, where the pictures are side by side, to when it is shrinked into mobile view, to this: https://imgur.com/a/SckIH8S

Comment: **<div class=".col-9">** - I don't think you want the period on the class name

Comment: must've been a typo. edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your container element a class of `container-fluid` then give its children a class of `col-xs-` accordingly.
For example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <img>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <img>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <img>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `container-fluid` class will make your page responsive. The `col-md-4` will split the 12 columns layout into three equal sized parts when the viewport is 992px wide or more. The `col-xs-6` will split the layout in two parts.

You can read more about it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/)

Comment: ahh I see. Thanks! I appreciate it